# How can I unit test Custom Date Deserializer using Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I just started to learn Unit testing.

I would like to Unit test custom date deserializer which looks like this:

**CustomDateDeserializer.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        Long toParse = p.getLongValue();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));

        String formattedActualDate = format.format(new Date(toParse));

        return formattedActualDate;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to test it?
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: (1) Don’t use `Date` and `SimpeDateFOrmat`. They are poorly designed and long outdated. (2) Go object-oriented. Don’t use a string for a date and time. Use an `Instant`. (3) Don’t use a GMT offset and pretend it’s a time zone. Use a proper time zone ID like for example Africa/Algiers or Africa/Tunis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, you have a JsonParser, you extract a long from it and turn it into a readable date.

Well, first, don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`: they're obsolete and the `java.time` API is much, much better than those. So that's what I'll use.

What you need is mocking the parameters. Both `JsonParser` and `DeserializationContext` are abstract classes so they'll be easy to mock.

And to mock, we use libraries such as Mockito or Powermock.

For the examples below, I used Mockito.

```
CustomDateDeserializer deserializer;
JsonParser parser;
DeserializationContext context;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
  deserializer = new CustomDateDeserializer();
  parser = mock(JsonParser.class);
  context = mock(DeserializationContext.class);
}

@Test
void testDeserialize() {
  when(parser.getLongValue()).thenReturn(12L*60*60*1000); // 1970-01-01T12:00:00.000Z
  
  String result = deserializer.deserialize(parser, context);
  
  assertEquals("01 Jan 1970 11:00:00 GMT+1");
}
```

But your implementation uses deprecated API... You should use java.time instead. Also, note Java allows you to make the return-type more specific than the overridden method so let's rewrite your method as well:

```
class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
  static final ZoneOffset ZONE_OFFSET = ZoneOffset.of("UTC+01:00");
  static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

  @Override
  // Note the return-type is String, not Object
  public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(p.getLongValue());
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZONE_OFFSET);
    return dateTime.format(FORMATTER);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this answer. I have a question when I use your code for deserialization in `LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpoch(instant, ZONE_OFFSET);` ofEpoch function is underlined red, and I can't use it. Do you know why is that? I have also updated my code with imports that I use for custom deserialization class.

Comment: @user9347049 Sorry, it was a mistake from my part. You have to use `LocalDateTime.ofInstant` not `LocalDateTime.ofEpoch`, it was a mistake from my part.

Comment: Thank you. Have another question when I try to implement your code prom Test part with `String result = deserializer.deserialize(parser, context);` is underlined red saying: `Required type:String Provided:Object. `assertEquals("01 Jan 1970 11:00:00 GMT+1");` part as well with error: `Cannot resolve method 'assertEquals(java.lang.String)'` Why is that?

Comment: It looks like you're very new to development, even newer to IDE. For the first one, I mentioned that the return-type of your `deserialize` method should not be `Object` but `String`. If you do that, the first red-underlined line will be okay. The method call `assertEquals` is a method from Junit's Assertions method. Try using it with `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;` below the `package` keyword in your Java file.

Comment: Yes, I am very new and still learning about everything. Your answer is great! It helped a lot to me, and thank you for that :) Thank you for your time and patience :)

Comment: Hi again me :) I was wondering if you could give me some guidance of what online tutorials or e-Books are best for unit testing, or what should I start with? In my project I have more stuff that I need to test, and probably I would need some good guidance. I do ask questions here and research a lot, but sometimes I don't get any answer that can help me. As you can see I do need it :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Usually the explanations on baeldung.com are effective. But their navigation is subpar, so try searching for "junit baeldung" or any topic then "baeldung" and you'll find answers to most of your questions. (Just so you know, I'm not affiliated with them, I just find them good at what they do.)

Comment: I did read them a lot. Well, thank you! Thank you for all your answers :)